# How to change the label of "A", "B", "C" e.t.c. in venn (R)

Tags: r, diagram, venn-diagram

I try to create a Venn Diagram with `venn()` function in R. It works but I want to be able to define my own labels instead of `"A"`, `"B"` e.t.c... I don't understand how one do that cause there is no label argument that can be passed to the function.

**EDIT**: Forgot to say that I use a list of vectors which contain strings...

*EDIT2:

it is the package "venn" from gplots:

```
library(gplots)
```

Example code:

variable list_ looks like this:

```
> list_
[[1]]
[1] "hejsan"   "pelle"    "svanslov"

[[2]]
[1] "kok"   "nalle" "pelle"
```

and then I do:

```
venn(list_)
```

which looks like this:

http://postimage.org/image/wpis8ny2b/deea76ff/

Comment: Could you post the code you use? Even though it doesn't do exactly what you want it to, it is much easier to help you if we know what you are doing, what packages you use and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `venn` function takes the labels in the plot from the names of the list elements.

```
names(list_) <- c("First list", "Second list")
venn(list_)
```

Comment: You're welcome! This behaviour is pretty common i R, but not very obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the venn() function that you are using. If you're willing to use a different package there is a short tutorial here -> http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/venn.htm that will let you do what you want with the "names" argument.

Comment: it is the package "venn" from gplots:

library(gplots)

Comment: http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/gplots/html/venn.html gives you the info you need: alternatively Backlin's answer :)